# How to display Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening using javascript in 12hours format

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is 4:11PM here now but my output is shown as 'Good Morning' - why is this happening?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function dateTime() {
    var ndate = new Date();
    var h = ndate.getHours() % 12;
    var format = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    var m = ndate.getMinutes().toString();
    var s = ndate.getSeconds().toString();

    if (h < 12) {
      h = "0" + h;
      $("h3.day-message").html("Good Morning");
    } else if (h < 18) {
      $("h3.day-message").html("Good Afternoon");
    } else {
      $("h3.day-message").html("Good Evening");
    }

    if (s < 10) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }

    if (m < 10) {
      m = "0" + m;
    }

    $('.date').html(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + format);
  }

  setInterval(dateTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="day-message"></h3>
<span class="date"></span>
```

Comment: Just try using `% 12` from this line `var h = ndate.getHours() % 12;`.

Comment: `h` will never be higher than 12. Please debug your code and test different values with `% 12` to understand what's happening and definitely see the documentation on the [**Remainder Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are using the modulo operator. This means that your `h > 12` check will never be hit as the remainder of the division cannot be greater than `12`. It's because of this your logic always believes it's still the morning. To fix this, just use a simple `<` check when comparing the hour figure.

Also note that you have some issues with the formatting of the date, such as appending extra zeroes so you end up with `011` as hour values. You can fix this by using `slice()`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function dateTime() {
    var ndate = new Date();
    var hours = ndate.getHours();
    var message = hours < 12 ? 'Good Morning' : hours < 18 ? 'Good Afternoon' : 'Good Evening';
    $("h3.day-message").text(message);

    $('.date').html(hours.leadingZeroes(2) + ":" + ndate.getMinutes().leadingZeroes(2) + ":" + ndate.getSeconds().leadingZeroes(2) + (hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'));
  }

  setInterval(dateTime, 1000);
});

Number.prototype.leadingZeroes = function(len) {
  return (new Array(len).fill('0', 0).join('') + this).slice(-Math.abs(len));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="day-message"></h3>
<span class="date"></span>
```

Comment: i'll try what you said,.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function dateTime() {
  var format="";
    var ndate = new Date();
 var hr = ndate.getHours();
    var h = hr % 12;
 
  if (hr < 12)
  {
        greet = 'Good Morning';
  format='AM';
  }
    else if (hr >= 12 && hr <= 17)
 {
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
  format='PM';
  }
    else if (hr >= 17 && hr <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';
 
    var m = ndate.getMinutes().toString();
    var s = ndate.getSeconds().toString();

    if (h < 12) {
      h = "0" + h;
      $("h3.day-message").html(greet);
    } else if (h < 18) {
      $("h3.day-message").html(greet);
    } else {
      $("h3.day-message").html(greet);
    }

    if (s < 10) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }

    if (m < 10) {
      m = "0" + m;
    }

    $('.date').html(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + format);
  }

  setInterval(dateTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="day-message"></h3>
<span class="date"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks dude u save my day. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating mode, so `h` will never be greater that 12

So, Instead of

```
var h = ndate.getHours() % 12;
```

Use it

```
var h = ndate.getHours();
```

Explaination: modulo operator(%) will divide total hours by 12 and return the Remainder.
For example if current time is 4 pm, I'll be 16 hours, so It'll return 4

Comment: Please add some explanation why it never will be higher 12. I'm sure OP has no idea what the modulo function is or the question wouldn't be asked.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery

```js
const messages = [
  { ampm: "am", "greet": 'Good Morning' },
  { ampm: "pm", "greet": 'Good Afternoon' },
  { ampm: "pm", "greet": 'Good Evening' }
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const dateSpan = document.getElementById("date");
  const message = document.getElementById("day-message");
  const dateTime = () => {
    let now = new Date(),
      hour = now.getHours(),
      hh = hour % 12, // (hour % 12).toString().padStart(2,"0") if you want leading 0
      mm = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
      ss = now.getSeconds(),
      period = 0;

    if (hour < 12) period = 0;
    else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 17) period = 1;
    else if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 24) period = 2;
    message.textContent = messages[period].greet;
    dateSpan.textContent = `${hh}:${mm}${messages[period].ampm}`; 

  };
  setInterval(dateTime, 500);
});
```

```html
<h3 id="day-message"></h3>
<span id="date"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening using javascript in 12hours format

```
const displayGreeting =()=>{

    const myDate = new Date();
    const hrs = myDate.getHours();
    let greet;

    if (hrs < 12)
        greet = 'Good Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
    else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';
        return  greet
  }
```